# Comparing 2 dates in Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I am just comparing 2 dates.

C#

```
  string args = string.Format("'{0}','{1}'
                            ,(DateTime)System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.MaxValue
                            , DateTime.Now);

        add.OnClientClick = String.Format("JSFunctn1({0}); return false;", args);

Js File:

JSFunctn1(maxDate, currentDate)
{
alert(maxDate);
alert(currentDate); // Both Dates displayed properly

if (currentDate >= maxDate) {
        alert("error"); //IT Comes here
    }
```

Can anyone tell me where am I wrong, It should not come in the loop, because max Date is 12/31/9999 12:00:00 AM

Comment: What are the values you see in `maxDate` and `currentDate` at client end ?

Comment: I wrote the maxDate : 12/31/9999 12:00:00 AM and currentDate is the currentTime; 6/4/2015 2:00:00 PM

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem is that you are comparing strings rather than dates.

Try this on the client:

```
if (Date.parse(currentDate) >= Date.parse(maxDate)) {
  alert('error');
}
```